# What's the difference it will make if ssh with a port other than the default?

Tags: ssh, port

When I ssh to a remote a server I usually use the default port or a port given to me, but I don't know why I need to use this port.  How and where are these ports defined? Why do we choose a certain port to ssh the remote server? What difference will it make? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a question about why SSH uses port 22, or why any IP service has ports?

Answer (score 2):

When you connect to anything (not just SSH) on another machine, you need a mechanism to tell the other machine *what* you are connecting to.  The IP address is used to route your connection across the internet (or local network) to the machine, the port tells that machine which program the connection goes to.

There's nothing magical about these numbers.  Any service can theoretically run on any port.  But then you'd never know which port to us.  Historically this problem has been solved by putting well known services on their own port and not use these ports for anything else.

In linux (and some other OS) there is a file named `/etc/services` which lists common services and the port they use.  You'll see that SSH is port 22, http is port 80, https is port 443...

You can move any service onto any port, but if you don't use the default then when someone tries to use that service *they* will need to know what port you have moved it to.

---

The difference it generally makes is simply how easily others can find the port.  Sometimes people don't want to use port 22 because when you open port 22 on any public IP, you'll get a few brute force SSH attacks per day.  By changing the port, those attackers don't generally find the right port number to attack (though they still might).  The down side is you have to tell all your users which port to use.